# Update "unsubscribe" information for email addresses

Tags: email, import, unsubscribe

I have a data set downloaded from MailChimp (pre-dating when we used CiviCRM) of people who hit "unsubscribe" for their email address.  I've used the "CVS Import Helper" extension to match each of these with their CiviCRM contact ID.

Now I'd like to process these unsubscriptions - but for people who have more than one email address, it seems correct to unsubscribe them from *just* the address they wanted to remove.  My assumption is that for some people, they may have been getting multiple messages, and intended to unsubscribe from one so they just get one message now.

Is there a way to do this using the "Import Contacts" or similar functionality?

Comment: CiviCRM doesn't really deal with unsubscribes on a per email basis, only per contact. So what are you hoping to have happen specifically? Put those emails on hold?

Answer (score 1):

To make sure I'm on the same page terminology wise: a contact **unsubscribes** from a specific list (allowing them to still get email from other lists still) but if they **opt-out** that means no emails should be sent to that specific email address. (Civi also adds another layer where you can mark a contact 'Do not email' - and no email will be sent to that contact at all.)

You could use the **On Hold - Opt Out** option, per email, on a contact but that will also prevent you from sending any mail to that email address.

You might be able to use the **Bulk Mailings?** checkbox and keep a separate email marked for bulk mailings. We don't use this as often but I'm pretty sure the way it works is: If the checkmark is not used then civi assumes it should send bulk mailings to the email marked primary. But once you use the checkmarks bulk mailings will only go to the email(s) that have been marked for bulk mailings.
[image]